# Find serial in a range

Tags: sql, database, spss

I have a dataset of 17 digit serials and another dataset of serial ranges. How can I find that which serial belong to which range?

For example:

```
id  dataset1:
1   54146000000012930
2   54146000000013000
3   54146000000013500
```

And dataset2:

```
id  from                to
1   54146000000012916   54146000000012935
2   64143001950000000   64143001950009999
3   54146000000012936   54146000000013035
4   64143001950010000   64143001950019999
5   64143001950020000   64143001950029999
6   54146000000013436   54146000000013535
```

Note that:

-the first 10 digits are static in range.

-the ranges are non overlapped .

My base tools are SPSS and SQL.

Thanks.

Comment: And the result should be?

Comment: are these 17 digit serials type of varchar ?

Comment: -the result should be the id of range for each serial.

Comment: yes. the data type is varchar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a `join`:

```
select d1.*, d2.*
from dataset1 d1 join
     dataset2 d2
     on d1.serial between d2.fromserial and d2.toserial;
```

This is a non-equijoin, meaning that the join condition is not `=`.

Answer (score 0):

In SPSS Statistics, you can do this using the SPSSINC TRANS extension command with the extendedTransforms.vlookupinterval function.